# Search in a .txt file a specific line and copy it in another file c#

Tags: c#, file-io

I have a .txt file with this content for example:

```
1
Hey, how are u
Ist everything ok ? 
I hope u are well 

2 I'm fine thanks 
Nice to hear from u 


3 Sounds great 
What are u doing now ? 
Hope u enjoy your stay
```

I need a method which i can give a number, for example 2 and the program should copy the whole text after the number 2 till number 3 in a new txt file. Downstairs i posted a solution how to identify the line, but now i don't know how to copy a certain part of the file

Comment: So you want a console application in which you enter a number and it returnes you the line (which starts with that number) and writes it to a file?

Comment: What have you tried? We can help you to fix errors if you show us some code.

Comment: You can check some sample codes here: [Code: Reading a Text File One Line at a Time (Visual C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287535(v=vs.71).aspx) [How to: Read From a Text File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezwyzy7b.aspx)

Comment: If the numbers in the first line are in order, simple increment through the lines will do. But if the numbers are in random (which seems it doesn't), parse the first `char` of the line then compare it to the number. `if (line_num == (int) Char.GetNumericValue(line[0]))`

Comment: I know how to read my txt file, my problem is that I don't know how can I look for a special number in my code and how to copy the text till the next number. The examples downstairs won't work because I save everything in am external txt file with more than 200 examples like above and I'm still adding stuff

Comment: Let's say you want to copy from char `2` to `3` (line 2). You can try reading `char` by `char`. When it reaches `2` then start copying to another file until it reaches char `3`. Use `StreamReader.Read()` to read every `char` in a file.

Comment: Had the same idea but isn't there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void RunSnippet()
{
    string input =
    "1 Hey, how are u\n" +
    "\n" +
    "2 I'm fine thanks\n" +
    "\n" +
    "3 Sounds great";

    Console.WriteLine(GetLine(3, input));
}

static string GetLine(int number, string content)
{
    return Regex.Split(content, "\n").First(l=> l.StartsWith(number.ToString()));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use regex

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input =
               "1 Hey, how are u\n" +
               "\n" +
               "2 I'm fine thanks\n" +
               "\n" +
               "3 Sounds great";

            string pattern = @"^(?'index'\d+)\s+(?'value'.*)";
            Regex expr = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);

            MatchCollection matches = expr.Matches(input);

            Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            foreach(Match match in matches)
            {
                dict.Add(int.Parse(match.Groups["index"].Value), match.Groups["value"].Value); 
            }

            string sentence2 = dict[2];

        }
    }
}
​
```